# Div background jquery switcher fails

Tags: php, jquery, image, magento, switch-statement

I have a simple background image switcher in a slider.

Defualt the normal enviroment(.nenv) image is displayed perfectly, but when i click at the enviroment(.env) view and then back again, jquery is setting all the backgroundimages in that div to the same image.

It should be like

```
<div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url('image1.png') no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>

<div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url('image2.png') no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>

<div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url('image3.png') no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>
```

But instead it's

```
<div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url('image1.png') no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>

<div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url('image1.png') no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>

<div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url('image1.png') no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>
```

Here's the php/jquery:

```
<div class="slides-container">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

        <script type="text/javascript" class="preserve">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                    jQuery('.env').click(function(){
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').removeAttr('style');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background', 'url(<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .'/catalog/product/'. $_product->getData('enviromental'); ?>)');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background-size', 'contain');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background-position', 'center');
                        //Buttons
                        jQuery('.env').css('color', '#009ab1');
                        jQuery('.env').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
                        jQuery('.nenv').css('color', 'black');
                        jQuery('.nenv').css('text-decoration', 'none');
                    })
                    jQuery('.nenv').click(function(){
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').removeAttr('style');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background', 'url(<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .'/catalog/product/'. $_product->getData('normal_enviromental'); ?>)');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background-size', 'contain');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
                        jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css('background-position', 'center');
                        //Buttons
                        jQuery('.nenv').css('color', '#009ab1');
                        jQuery('.nenv').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
                        jQuery('.env').css('color', 'black');
                        jQuery('.env').css('text-decoration', 'none');
                    })
                });
                </script>

        <div class="sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?> singleartist-picture" style="background:url(<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .'/catalog/product/'. $_product->getData('normal_enviromental'); ?>) no-repeat center;background-size:contain;"></div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
Instead of defining all the singleartist-picture class i passed them with a specific id as following:

```
jQuery('.sartistpicture-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').css
```

Instead of

```
jQuery('.singleartist-picture').css
```